# Set a script to run automatically after apt-get dist-upgrade, install, remove and purge?

Tags: apt

How would I automatically run a script after the `apt-get` actions `dist-upgrade`, `install`, `remove` and `purge`? Is there a suitable way of hooking into the APT lifecycle and run a custom script?

Comment: Why don't you use aliases or include `apt-get` in a/your custom script ?

Comment: I'm looking for this answer too, except with apt-get update. @user55822, one reason would be because aliases only apply to your personal bash sessions. Therefore, anything besides you actually running `apt-get update` in a terminal (e.g. the update cron job, synaptic, etc.) won't make your script run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can automatically run a script by creating a new file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99ownscript` containing:

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh"; };
```

Note that this file does not have to be executable, just 644 mode is sufficient.