# How to auto restart services when you get security updates?

Tags: security, services

That's related to the heartbleed bug. While my server (12.04 LTS) was configured to perform unattended install of all security updates, it seems that nginx was not restarted so it was still  affected by the bug.

By manually performing the restart the problem was solved, but I am looking for an automatic solution to this kind of problem.

Note: I am using the nginx from nginx.org, not the one from Ubuntu which is, ancient.

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70686/how-to-run-a-command-after-apt-get-upgrade) regarding `checkrestart` (accepted answer at bottom) and [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203256/set-a-script-to-run-automatically-after-apt-get-dist-upgrade-install-remove-an) specifically about how to run custom scripts.

Comment: Are you aware that is the package maintainer responsibility (in this case, nginx) to restart the servers when the updates are applied?